# I am stuck with the usage of date field

Tags: php, date

I have 3 date fields (Loan_Date, loan_date1 and loan_date2)in my database and have to assign the value to a $ldate variable if not date field is not empty. I have shown below the code i used to compare if date is empty

```
    $ldate="";

    if(empty(strtotime($row['loan_date1']))){
    $ldate=$row['Loan_Date']; }


    if(strtotime($row['loan_date1'])>0 and 
    empty(strtotime($row['loan_date2']))){
        $ldate=$row['loan_date1'];  }
```

is the above code workable??

Comment: Please clarify your requirement more.

Comment: is the code  if(empty(strtotime($row['loan_date1'])) correct

Comment: Try  if(empty($row['loan_date1']))